# Rails adding existing record to new record in many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails and I had a question about many-to-many associations. I have a rails app that is running great so far. It has task, mission, and sub-task models. A sub-tasks can belong to a task and a task can have many tasks. A task can have many missions and a mission can have many tasks. So far I am able to add a new mission to a task and a new task to a mission. I can also add the either a task or a mission separately. However, my question revolves around associating two existing records or an existing record to a new record. For example, if I am creating a new mission, is it possible to use collection_select to populate a dropdown with Task.all and that the selection from the dropdown go into @mission.tasks?

Comment: Can you post your models with the associations please.  Might just be me but it's easier to visualise the setup that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hook into the `"<association>_ids"` getter and setter methods.  eg

```
mission = Mission.new(:name => "Foo", :task_ids => [123,456])
mission.save
```

`mission` should now be associated with tasks 123 & 456.

In your form, you would normally be setting up params with names like "mission[name]", "mission[description]" etc, and then in the controller doing something like

```
mission = Mission.new(params[:mission])
```

Hook into this pattern by, in your view, having a select, or checkboxes, with the name attribute set to `"mission[task_ids][]"`.  The [] at the end tells it to put the values into an array.